# Prove that $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}(A+I)$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is $2\times2$, and given eigenvalues of $A$ are $1,-2$, prove $$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}(A+I)$$

I've tried expanding matrix $A$ into its components, and solve for components of $A$ with given eigenvalues, but I'm still not getting anywhere. What properties can help here?

Comment: what is the characteristic polynomial of $A \; \; ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using that $n=2$, since all eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct, we know that it is diagonalizable. So 
$$
A=S\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}S^{-1}
$$
for some invertible matrix $S$. Now, since 
$$
\frac12\,\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}+I\right)=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-1/2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}^{-1},
$$
after conjugating with $S$ we get the same equation for $A$.

**Edit:** How to use the above. 
\begin{align}
A^{-1}
&=\left(S\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}S^{-1}\right)^{-1}=S\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}S^{-1}\\ \ \\
&=S\left(\frac12\,\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}+I\right)\right)S^{-1}\\ \ \\
&=\frac12\,\left(S\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}S^{-1}+SS^{-1}\right)\\ \ \\
&=\frac12\,(A+I)
\end{align}

Comment: Nice, probably would've been my approach as well. (That $X$ should probably be an $S$.)

Comment: Edited, thanks :)

Comment: thanks, why can A be reduced to the eigenvalue matrix? I understand the diagonalizability and A = SBS^-1, but I don't follow the next step.

Comment: As it says in the answer, conjugate by $S$.

Comment: 'conjugate' means conjugate transpose? What is conjugating by S?

Comment: @user14042: "conjugate" in my sentence is a verb, not an adjective. Conjugating $B$ by $S$ means $SBS^{-1}$.

Comment: do you mean we take the A from the original equation and substitute with A=SBS^-1?

Comment: I included the explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$ p_A(x)=(x-1)(x+2)=x^2+x-2$$
and $p_A(A)=0$ by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: why is the characteristic of A (x-1)(x+2) if the (1,2) and (2,1) entries are not defined to be zero?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial must be $(x-1)(x+2)$ because $A$ is $2\times 2$ with eigenvalues $1$ and $-2$.

Comment: oh I see! Then the next step is using CH theorem to define the p(A)=0 which then gives 4 equations that can solve elements of A?

Comment: No, instead start with $p_A(A)=0$ and multiply by $A^{-1}$. There are infinitely many $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ with eigenvalues $1$ and $-2$, so you have no hope of solving for the entries of $A$.

Comment: Oh! I got it, then just simple matrix operations. How do you come up with such a solution? I was clueless.

Comment: If you're looking for some sort of polynomial equation involving $A$, Cayley-Hamilton is often a good place to start.